# How to differ MySQL and MS SQL database from code?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database

We have two database and single method.
In our case queries for MySQL and Ms SQL db are different.
We need to define when use query to needed db.
How can I code in C# to find which db is using now?

Comment: You probably have different connection strings.

Comment: At some point you will have made the decision on which database you are connecting to - as @PawełDyl said you need different connections strings. So you could have a field (Boolean for two database, numeric/enum if you may in future have more than two) as part of your class - and use that flag to decide which query you will use.

Comment: Or you could make use of the benefits of C# interfaces. Define an interfaces to include all of your required methods to access the database - then create database specific classes implementing the interface. Use a field of the interface type & instantiate the correct database class type on opening the database. This is very easily extensible to other database types if required. (NOTE - deriving from a  base class is another possibility).

Comment: you maybe want to think about a database abstraction layer ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer

Comment: the dependency injection pattern might be useful as well. Then you can have some sort of setting in your environment which controls which DB is currently in use and use that information to decide which database interface to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following:

- Add an enum to the method input parameters which decide which kind of
  database should be used (You have to know this information before
  calling the method)
- Inside the method, depending on the enum, I would choose the proper
  query and then call a different method for running the MySQL query and
  one for running MS SQL. In one case using OracleConnection and in the other using SqlConnection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use naive method to check version which will give sql server etc., This you can use both in sql server as well as mysql

```
SELECT @@version
```

Answer (score 0):

If it needs to be in one method you could place using statements within one method, e.g.,

```
using(SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection("FirstConnectionString"))
{
    // your Query
}


using(SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection("SecondConnectionString"))
{
    // your Query
}
```

Where in First and Second Connections strings you define which database you refer to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this: make a new class for both methods you are using, in the mysql you put something like this, or whatever you have in your code

`public void GetHighscore(int CurrScore)
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new                                     MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=basket;Uid=root;pwd=;");
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "select * from tblhighscore where id = 0";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrScore", CurrScore);
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            conn.Close();
        }`

and for the ms sql you make another class with your own queries and stuff, i think the only difference should be the name of the sql, for example: MySql would be just sql.

You can call upon the mysql one with the following code, the dbConnect.GetHighscore is a reference to a piece of code in the mysql class, it will execute all the code in that piece of code.:

`dbConnect clDb = new dbConnect();
            dbConnect.GetHighscore;`